# PHP 'hash' method 'raw_data' parameter

Tags: php, encryption, hash

Trying to understand last parameter `raw_data` of [php's hash method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Documentation states `raw_data:`

> When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase
>   hexits.

What scenarios would this be used? 
When would we want binary data vs hexits?

Comment: When you don't want to use twice as much storage space as you need to. Maybe you're storing the results of a large number of calculations in an in-memory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary mode to change the encoding from hexits to something else, e.g.

```
echo base64_encode(hash('md5', 'hello', true));
// XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg==
```

Additionally, storing the raw data in your database takes up less space; you do compromise on readability though, it's not practical to copy/paste from your database anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you set this variable true you will get binary result. Such result is smaller but there are appliances where you cannot use it (for instance, you cannot pass it in url) - in such cases you can set raw_data=false to get just a string where every byte of hash is represented by two hexadecimal numbers (so byte 10111001 will be represented as B5). This representation can be easily converted back to binary sequence and can be used everywhere you can use regular string but will be much larger.